# Parse log file and then redirect outputs to some other file

Tags: perl

I am trying in my script to parse some number of files and redirecting the output to some other file. Please help me out, what I am doing wrong. Because I am creating separate file for each output, but it's creating a common .txt file, and my code is not working.

Below is the code for creating output file:

```
open( $m1logFIle, "> $m1log.txt" ) || die "\n Could not create write file.\n\n";
open( $g1logFIle, "> $g1log.txt" ) || die "\n Could not create write file.\n\n";
open( $V1logFIle, "> $VOD1og.txt") || die "\n Could not create write file.\n\n";
```

I am printing it to the file with the following code:

```
print $V1logFIle  "-V1 Success @ $curr_exectime(ms)\n\n";
```

Comment: You should really include the value of [`$!`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24! "perldoc perlvar") in your error message like it shows in the documentation for [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html "perldoc -f open"). Or you could just [`use autodie;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html "perldoc autodie"), and get rid of the `|| die ...;`. Also you should always add [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html "perldoc strict") and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html "perldoc warnings") until you know exactly why it is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to make some assumptions here.

1. You are not using `use strict` and `use warnings`, which is why you cannot figure out why this is happening.
2. When you say `but its creating a common file .txt file`, you actually mean that it is creating a file with the name `.txt`.
3. Your variables `$m1log`, `$g1log` and `$VOD1og` are somehow undefined.

So, to fix this, add

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

to your script and fix the errors and warnings that appear. If your problem still persists, make sure your variables actually contain what you think they do, for example by printing them with the `Data::Dumper` module:

```
use Data::Dumper;
...
print Dumper $VOD1og;
```

You will find that `Data::Dumper` is an excellent debugging tool.

**TL;DR:**

```
my $VOD1og;         # undefined variable
print "> $VOD1og";  # prints "> " because $VOD1og is empty
```

Without `use warnings`, no warning is given.

Answer (score 0):

if there is a variable `$m1log` existing then it should be

```
open( $m1logFIle, ">", $m1log.".txt" ) || die "\n Could not create write file.\n\n";
```

Comment: While I agree that this is a better way to write those lines, it does not actually help with the problem the OP is complaining about.

Comment: initially am defining variable..
my $m1logFILE;

But at last still am getting some undefined file name as an output..
like - GLOB(0x155476c).txt, GLOB(0x155474c).txt... , where am doing wrong??